# This property is deprecated, please use [toolbarTextStyle] and [titleTextStyle] instead

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class MyTheme {
  static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
//textTheme is deprecated
     textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      )
      );

  static ThemeData darkTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  );
}
```

Error:

```
'textTheme' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no longer used, please use toolbarTextStyle and titleTextStyle instead.





 "textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme,"
```

I was trying a new walkaround for this but doesn't seem to work.

```
 //  titleTextStyle: TextStyle((context).textTheme),"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

    class MyTheme {
    static ThemeData lightTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        toolbarTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      ));

     static ThemeData darkTheme(BuildContext context) => ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      );
  }
```

Comment: Error Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)

Comment: toolbarTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
        titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,  shows error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ah yes, a 'const' before 'AppBarTheme' produces the error. Remove and place it in front of 'IconThemeData' instead. I hope it helped ;)